# Как лучше создать CMS для нескольких сайтов?

Tags: java, php, cms

Здравствуйте!

Уже неделю ломаю голову... как же лучше создать CMS для сайта?

В последнее время очень часто создаю интернет-магазины и сайты-визитки. В связи с чем появилась идея упростить эту задачу за счет более удобной CMS.

CMSку хочу держать на своем сервере, как и сайты, чтобы в последствии создать единый интернет-магазин (подобие taobao.com) - это не основная задача. Основная цель CMS её постоянное обновление (добавление различных модулей). Т.е. исправил один файл на своем сервере, и у всех пользователей соответственно это изменение появилось.

У меня уже больше сорока сайтов, неудобно обновлять старую CMS, так как приходится "ручками" лезть в каждую.

---

**Вопросы:**

1. Хочу сделать единую базу данных для всех пользователей, в которой выборка будет по ID пользователя. Допустим, если у пользователя под управлением находится интернет-магазин, когда он добавляет товар, то данные помещаются в базу данных товаров всех пользователей, но если товаров будет миллион (к примеру), тогда запрос на выборку будет очень долгим (`SELECT * all_products WHERE user_id='$user_id'`) - можно ли так делать?
2. Может быть вообще лучше делать CMS, которую непосредственно нужно помещать в директорию сайта?

В общем, жду совета от опытных программистов! Всем, кто подскажет, как лучше и как не стоит делать, буду безумно благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Лучше взять готовую CMS и заняться чем нить более интересным, чем велосипедостроением.